# Не получается обновить дату в таблице

Tags: python, sql, datetime, psycopg2, передача-параметров

Хочу обновить дату в таблице. Вот отрывок кода:

```
today=datetime.date.today()
salary = input('Введите сумму зачисления:') 
id = int(input('Введите id сотрудника'))
cursor.execute(f'''UPDATE public.salary SET  dttm = {today}, salary = {salary}where employee_id = {id}''')
connection.commit()
```

Есть колонки: `salary, employee_id, dttm` (`dttm` - в формате text).

Пытаюсь сделать обновление `dttm` и `salary`, но после выполнения кода, `salary` меняется на указанное, а `dttm` становится `1990`.

В чём проблема?

Пробовал `today=datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, тоже не помогает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL надо "параметризовать" - иначе вы открываете дыру в безопасности и даете возможность использовать [`SQL Injections`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Кроме того при использовании параметров SQL литералы передаются SQL серверу с правильным типом данных - это должно решить проблему с датами.

Попробуйте так:

```
sql = '''UPDATE public.salary SET  dttm = %s, salary = %s where employee_id = %s'''
parms = [today, salary, id]
cursor.execute(sql, parms)
```

Comment: Или же cursor.execute("UPDATE public.salary SET  dttm = ?, salary = ? where employee_id = ?", (today, salary, id))

Comment: Спасибо! помогло

Comment: @dhvcc, это фактически тоже самое... Вид поддерживаемых `placeholders` зависит от реализации драйвера БД - знак вопроса работает для SQLite и, по-моему, для MySQL. На счет PostgreSQL - не уверен, что `psycopg2` поддерживает `?` в качестве `placeholders`. Лично я предпочитаю общаться с БД через посредника - SQL Alchemy (он роддерживает все известные виды placeholders)

Comment: @Dudd1, был рад помочь)

Comment: @dhvcc, [а вы уверены, что `?` поддерживается `psycopg2`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1100)?? В [документации](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html) я не нашел упоминаний о его поддержке

Comment: @MaxU думал, что речь идет об sqlalchemy, перепутал

Comment: А можно ли как-то вытащить данные с таблицы не создавая класс с таблицей? используя sqlalchemy

Comment: @Dudd1, можно, используя, например, Pandas